# How to manually compute PCA transformation as performed by predict() following pcrcomp() in R?

Tags: r, pca

How to manually compute PCA transformation as performed by `predict()` following `pcrcomp()` in R?

Example:

```
#loading data
data(iris)

#PCA
ir.pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4],scale=T,center=F)

#date frame to check
dt <- data.frame(1,0,0,0)
names(dt) <- names(iris[,1:4])

#prediction how it is computed?
predict(ir.pca,dt)

#things of PCA
ir.pca$rotation
ir.pca$center
ir.pca$scale
```

if the center is FALSE then equation is obvious:

```
predict(ir.pca,dt)[1] == dt[1,1] * ir.pca$rotation[1,1] / ir.pca$scale[1]
```

but what if the center is TRUE? Then I have no idea how to write a formula using the `center`, `rotation` and `scale`.

---

manual example:

```
VALUE: 1
CENTER: 5.843333
SCALE: 0.8280661
ROTATION: 0.5210659

(1-5.84333)/0.8280661*0.5210659 = -3,047698
```

and the "prediction" returns -3,282753

```
-3,047698 <> -3,282753
```

;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing the centering and scaling is just a simple subtraction and division each, and the `%*%` [operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) does the trick for the rotation (useful for multi-sample-dataframes):

```
ir.pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4],scale=T,center=T)

# [...]

s <- 1 
if(ir.pca$scale) {
    s <- ir.pca$scale
}

cent <- 0
if(ir.pca$center) {
    cent <- ir.pca$center
}

predict(ir.pca,dt)
#            PC1      PC2       PC3       PC4
# [1,] -3.282753 8.841321 -1.193984 0.2203813

((as.matrix(dt) - cent) / s ) %*% ir.pca$rotation
#            PC1      PC2       PC3       PC4
# [1,] -3.282753 8.841321 -1.193984 0.2203813
```

Comment: can you show me your answer on real numbers like imagine i have value, rotation, center and scale. What is the formula? (VALUE - CENTER) / SCALE * ROTATION ???

Comment: @faryzeusz It's exactly as you suggested: (VALUE - CENTER) / SCALE * ROTATION. The results are shown in the answer in the commented out parts of the code.

Comment: but it doesn't work on my example :(

Comment: @faryzeusz OK, it seems to work for the example you provided in the question. Maybe you need to update your question and also add the example where this does not work so that we see what's the issue.

Comment: can you look down, please ?